# Using FROM statement in dockerfile

Tags: docker

Sorry I am a beginner in docker.

Let's say I write `FROM my-docker-image` in Dockerfile.

If I have multiple versions of `my-docker-image`, which one will be used if  I write `FROM my-docker-image`?

If I want to use a specific version, can I add tag like `FROM my-docker-image:xxx`?

Comment: If you don't specify a tag, the assumed tag is `latest`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that's correct, you will have to use:

```
FROM my-docker-image:1.0.0
```

It is also possible to have multiple *FROM* in your Dockerfile

You could learn more about the FROM directive [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from).